# PROJ.4 - General Parameters: +no_defs

Tags: qgis, proj

Within a QGIS-course I would like to tell a bit about the proj.4 parameters. However, I'm not sure about the **"+no_defs"** parameter. 
The proj.4 website (http://proj4.org/parameters.html#parameter-list) says:

> +no_defs   Don't use the /usr/share/proj/proj_def.dat defaults file

Can anyone explain me what this means? (What would it mean to use the /usr/share/proj/proj_def.dat defaults file?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally I found this thread, which answers the question for my needs:

> The "no_defs" item ensures that no defaults are read from the defaults
>   files. Sometimes they cause suprising problems.

http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/mapserver-users/2003-November/046863.html

Answer (score 5):

In *modern* versions of the library, `+no_defs` means nothing.

Since v6.0.0, the default settings file has been removed. 
That means that **the +no_defs option is obsolete** if you're using modern versions of the libraries.